# getting an "Expected token Lparen dot 'identifier' " error on last function, anyone know what's wrong?

Tags: remix

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;

contract insure {
  address public doctor;

  function Person() private {
    doctor = msg.sender;
  }
  modifier onlyDoctor {
    require(msg.sender == doctor);
    _;
  }
}

contract postRecord is insure {
  string diagnosis;

  struct patient {
      address client;
      bool consent;
      bytes32 name;
   }

  event Post(string records);

  function modify(string records) private onlyDoctor {
      diagnosis = records;
  }

  function Person() private {
      doctor = msg.sender;
  }

  modifier rightPerson {
      if (msg.sender != doctor){
        throw;
      }else{
        _;
      }
  function returnString() public payable {
     Post(records);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a curly brace to close out the `rightPerson` modifier. It should go before the line `function returnString...`.

(Note that `records` is also an undeclared identifier, so you'll still have a compilation error after fixing the missing curly brace.)